# React grid gallery lazy loading on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React grid gallery(https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery) to display images, but I can't lazy load as the scroll user on the page.

```js
                  <Gallery
                    images={this.props.newExamples}
                    enableImageSelection
                    thumbnailImageComponent={ImageComponent}
                    rowHeight={this.props.newExamples[0].thumbnailHeight}
                    margin={10}
                    onSelectImage={(index, image) => this.onSelectImageNewExample(index, image)}
                  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I used react-lazy-load-image-component in thumbnailImageComponent like this:

```
    class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render () {
        console.log(this.props.imageProps)
        return (
                <LazyLoadImage
                    height={this.props.imageProps.style.width}
                    width={this.props.imageProps.style.width} 
                    src={this.props.imageProps.src} 
                    />
        );
    }
}
```

edit with functional component for [ANimator120](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12427268/animator120):

```
const ImageComponent = (props) => {
  const { imageProps } = props;

  return (
    <LazyLoadImage
      height={imageProps.style.width}
      width={imageProps.style.width}
      src={imageProps.src}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: How would you do this with a function component when we can't use ```this```?